# dreamweaver keep open bracket at same line PHP

Tags: php, format, line, dreamweaver

I have a problem with the code formatting in Dreamweaver

Default formatting by Dreamweaver:

```
<?php
    if(a>10){
    }
    
    function test (){
    }
    
    ?>
```

My preferred formatting:

```
 <?php
    if(a>10)
    {

    }
        
    function test ()
    {
    }
        
  ?>
```

How do I change it?

Comment: [Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) before changing anything

Answer (score 0):

As official guide([link](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/user-guide.html/dreamweaver/using/format-code.ug.html)) said:

- Create a new file in the site root with filename as .jsbeautifyrc
- Copy paste below default formatting rules for CSS, JS, and PHP in .jsbeautifyrc and save the file:

  ```
  { 
    "js": {

       "eol": "\n",

       "preserve_newlines": true,

       "max_preserve_newlines": 3,

       "space_after_anon_function": true,

       "keep_array_indentation": false,

       "space_before_conditional": true,

       "break_chained_methods": false,

       "unescape_strings": false,

       "wrap_line_length": 0,

       "end_with_newline": true,

       "comma_first": false,

       "operator_position": "after-newline"

   },

   "css": {

       "preserve_newlines": false,

       "selector_separator_newline" : false,

       "end_with_newline": false,

       "newline_between_rules": false,

       "space_around_selector_separator": true

   },

   "php": {

       "eol": "\n",

       "preserve_newlines": true,

       "max_preserve_newlines": 3,

       "space_after_anon_function": true,

       "brace_style": "collapse",

       "keep_array_indentation": false,

       "space_before_conditional": true,

       "break_chained_methods": false,

       "unescape_strings": false,

       "wrap_line_length": 0,

       "end_with_newline": false,

       "comma_first": false,

       "space_in_paren":true

    }

  }
  ```
- Edit the default rules to change the default code formatting rules as per below table and save the changes.
- Relaunch Dreamweaver and apply code formatting for a CSS, JS, and PHP file.

Code is formatted as per the updated formatting rules.

---

You need to change `brace_style` with `expand`

Comment: how change php rules in dreamweare

Comment: I wrote it above